# Filter foreignkey choices in django admin changeform based on property of a foreignkey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin, modelform

I have some models that look similiar to this (vastly simplified):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    country_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

In the dropdown for authors in the auto-generated book admin page, I have a list of all the Authors.

However, I want to be able to FIRST select a country_of_birth to pre-filter the queryset of possible authors. I think this first requires adding another field to the book admin not tied to the book model....
I've looked [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403060642/http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/filtering-dropdown-lists-in-the-django-admin/) but it doesn't *appear* to cover exactly what I am trying to do... any ideas?